# KeyError: 'value' while connecting to Onedrive app python

Tags: python, onedrive

I am trying to connect to onedrive app using OneDrive SDK for Python to get the shareable link of any folder. The code I am using is:

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_id = your_client_id
client_secret = your_client_secret
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)
# If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
# which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
```

It redirects me to the microsoft login page for my microsoft account and after that I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-099411646fc4> in <module>()
      4 # If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
      5 # which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
----> 6 service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
      7 auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
      8 client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\onedrivesdk\helpers\resource_discovery.py in get_service_info(self, access_token)
     24         headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
     25         response = json.loads(requests.get(self._discovery_service_url, headers=headers).text)
---> 26         service_info_list = [ServiceInfo(x) for x in response['value']]
     27         trimmed_service_info_list = [si for si in service_info_list
     28                                      if si.capability == 'MyFiles' and si.service_api_version == 'v2.0']

KeyError: 'value'
```

Can someone help me in solving the issue?

Comment: looks like an error with the module. Why don't you raise an issue on the module's github repo.

Comment: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/issues/26